# PartialChain error in X509Chain when building certificate chain?

Tags: c#, pkcs

I'm encountering a PartialChain error when using the X509Chain class in C# to build a certificate chain. The error message states: "Cannot build a certificate chain for a trusted root authority."

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
public X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificateFromCSR(byte[] csrBytes)
{
    var csr = CertificateRequest.LoadSigningRequest(csrBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    
    using var issuerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_settings.PfxPath, _settings.PfxPassword);
    var notBefore = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var notAfter = notBefore.AddYears(1);
    var serialNumber = GenerateSerialNumber();

    var issuerKey = issuerCertificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    var signatureGenerator = X509SignatureGenerator.CreateForRSA(issuerKey, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    var issuerName = new X500DistinguishedName(issuerCertificate.SubjectName.Name);

    var certGenerator = csr.Create(issuerName, signatureGenerator, notBefore, notAfter, serialNumber);

    var sanExtension = csr.CertificateExtensions.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Oid.Value == "2.5.29.17");

    if (sanExtension != null)
    {
        var sanExtensionValue = sanExtension.RawData;
        certGenerator.Extensions.Add(new X509Extension(sanExtension.Oid, sanExtensionValue, sanExtension.Critical));
    }

    // Create a certificate chain and add the issuer certificate
    using var chain = new X509Chain();
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(issuerCertificate);

    // Build the chain
    var chainBuilt = chain.Build(certGenerator);

    // Check if the chain status has any errors
    if (!chainBuilt || chain.ChainStatus.Any(status => status.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError))
    {
        // Print out the chain status information
        foreach (var chainStatus in chain.ChainStatus)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Chain error: {Status} {StatusInformation}", chainStatus.Status, chainStatus.StatusInformation);
        }

        // Handle the error here
        throw new Exception("Chain build failed");
    }

    // Check the last element in the chain to verify that it's indeed the root CA certificate you expect
    var rootCert = chain.ChainElements[^1].Certificate;
    
    if (!rootCert.Equals(issuerCertificate))
    {
        // Handle the error here
        throw new Exception("Incorrect root certificate");
    }

    // Get the chain elements
    var chainElements = chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>();

    // Concatenate the certificates in the chain
    var certificateChain = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    
    foreach (var chainElement in chainElements)
    {
        certificateChain.Add(chainElement.Certificate);
    }

    // Export the certificate chain as a PFX file
    var pfxBytes = certificateChain.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, _settings.PfxPassword);

    // Create the final certificate from the exported PFX bytes
    var finalCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes, _settings.PfxPassword);

    return finalCertificate;
}
```

I have verified that the certificate is valid and trusted. However, the PartialChain error occurs consistently. I have also checked the certificate stores and ensured that all the necessary intermediate and root certificates are present.

The CA certificate is issued like this:

```
$caName = "RemoteMaster Internal CA"
$destDirectory = "InternalCA"
$opensslPath = "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe"

# Ensure destination directory exists
if (-not (Test-Path $destDirectory)) {
    New-Item -Path $destDirectory -ItemType Directory
    Write-Host "Created directory: $destDirectory" -ForegroundColor Green
}

# Generate a private key
& $opensslPath genpkey -algorithm RSA -out "$destDirectory\$caName.key" -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096

# Generate a CSR using the private key
& $opensslPath req -new -key "$destDirectory\$caName.key" -out "$destDirectory\$caName.csr" -subj "/CN=$caName"

# Create an OpenSSL configuration file
$config = @"
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[ req_distinguished_name ]
CN = $caName
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
"@
$config | Out-File "$destDirectory\openssl.cnf" -Encoding ascii

# Generate a self-signed certificate with Basic Constraints set to CA:TRUE
& $opensslPath x509 -req -days 3650 -in "$destDirectory\$caName.csr" -signkey "$destDirectory\$caName.key" -out "$destDirectory\$caName.crt" -extfile "$destDirectory\openssl.cnf" -extensions v3_req

# Convert the certificate and private key to a PFX file
& $opensslPath pkcs12 -export -out "$destDirectory\$caName.pfx" -inkey "$destDirectory\$caName.key" -in "$destDirectory\$caName.crt" -name $caName

Write-Host "Generated self-signed root CA certificate and exported to PFX." -ForegroundColor Green

# Import the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
Import-Certificate -FilePath "$destDirectory\$caName.crt" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\Root"
Write-Host "Added CA certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities store." -ForegroundColor Green
```

What could be causing this PartialChain error? How can I troubleshoot and resolve it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem's been taken care of. I should have done it like this

```
public X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificateFromCSR(byte[] csrBytes)
{
    if (csrBytes == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csrBytes));
    }

    var csr = CertificateRequest.LoadSigningRequest(csrBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    using var caCertificate = new X509Certificate2(_settings.PfxPath, _settings.PfxPassword);
    var subjectName = new X500DistinguishedName(caCertificate.SubjectName);
    var signatureGenerator = X509SignatureGenerator.CreateForRSA(caCertificate.GetRSAPrivateKey(), RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    var notBefore = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var notAfter = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1);
    var serialNumber = GenerateSerialNumber();

    var certificate = csr.Create(subjectName, signatureGenerator, notBefore, notAfter, serialNumber);

    return certificate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**